# Sci-fi webcomic about a war with guns that use caseless ammunition

Tags: story-identification, aliens, webcomics

I remember reading a cool comic online and the thing I remember most is that instead of using guns with magazines, they had tubes or rods of ammo and the gun would automatically cut up the ammo rod when firing. I think there were alien races as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, do you have any sense of whether this was a Western or Eastern comic? Or any ideas about which website/s you might have read this on?

Comment: Weapons in Mass Effect are said to work by accelerating a tiny piece of metal shaved off a block of metal internal to the weapon to very high speeds. Could it have been some Mass Effect related comic? Plenty of aliens in Mass Effect.